# Tagging consecutive repeating items where n = 4, for example

Tags: sql-server

This code works well at tagging all items but I can't adapt it to work only when there is a defined number of repeats.  Any ideas?

```
UPDATE nl
    SET nl.description = (
        SELECT MAX(l.id2_location)
        FROM locations l 
        WHERE l.id_location = nl.id_location
    )
FROM newlocations nl
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM locations l
    WHERE l.id_location = nl.id_location
);
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8c33/16

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Consecutive implies some sort of ordering.

Comment: You want to search for "running total" using a windowing function (partition by). That makes this pretty easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the fiddle you provided, here is a modified update:

```
UPDATE nl set [description] = sq.Location2
FROM newlocations nl
  inner join (
    select l.id_location, max(l.id2_location) as [Location2]
    from locations l
    group by l.id_location
  ) sq on nl.id_location = sq.id_location
where exists (
  select 0 from newlocations c
  where c.id_location = nl.id_location
  group by c.id_location
  having count(*) >= 4
);
```

Notice that in your sample data, there are no `id_location` values that repeat exactly 4 times, that's why I put `>=` in the filtering condition.

Comment: Thank you.   It works and updates all when n>=4 as intended.  However, can the consecutive criteria also be added.  So only update if the id's are consecutive and >=4?

Comment: @user3359706, "consecutive" assumes some way in which items are ordered, and none are apparent from your question. By itself, table rows do not have any particular order - it's not a spreadsheet.

Comment: outline query   -SELECT all FROM table with the same description on multiple adjacent rows for >= 4 rows and set tag = 'y' and order by id 
                                                                                              (id,description, tag),(1, 'xxx', 'n'),(2, 'xxx', 'n'),(3, 'xxx', 'n'),(7, 'xxx', 'n'),(5, 'xxx', 'n'),(8, 'xxx', 'n'), (4, 'xxx', 'n'), (6, 'zzz', 'n')
             
desired result 

(1, 'xxx', 'y')
(2, 'xxx', 'y')
(3, 'xxx', 'y')
(4, 'xxx', 'y')
(5, 'xxx', 'y')

Comment: @user3359706, It would be better if you would update your fiddle, to make it completely clear.

Comment: Thank you for the initial solution.  I've asked another question to follow up.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357355/how-to-tag-a-group-of-repeating-items-if-the-ids-are-consecutive-for-n-rows